# how to transfer files from one ec2 instance to s3 bucket of different account directly?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i want to move my files from one ec2 instance to another s3 bucket of different account.
i can follow these steps:

- transfer my ec2 files to s3 bucket of same account
- sync my s3 bucket with another s3 bucket of different account

But i want to directly move my files to their s3 bucket. Also i have pem file and hostname of their ec2 instance which i was using to connect their ec2 instance.
Actually, i am generating files through python script. so is there any way to directly save the generated files to their s3 bucket from my script without saving to my local ec2.

Comment: Did you try following the steps here? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: @drumhellerb i followed this Resource-based policies and IAM policies but i don't know what to do after that, i mean what code i need to write to transfer the files.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, since there are so many questions being asked (transfer, sync, save directly, "my local ec2" vs "their ec2 instance" etc). Could you possibly edit your question to clearly state what you are wanting to do and what specific problem you are facing?